# Android: Positioning 2 bitmaps on a Canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, dimension

I take picture and obtain a Bitmap (bitmap), when I take the picture there is an image I would like to stay on the top (bitmao2). So to save the picture with the image on it I use a canvas. I would like to position bitmap2 on bitmap exactly how it is positioned when I take the picture.
Here is what I do

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
    int width=bitmap.getWidth();
    int height=bitmap.getHeight();
    Bitmap bitmap2 = GameActivity.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(gameactivity.getResources(), R.drawable.fire16,width1 );
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,width,height,matrix,true);  

    ImageView image = (ImageView) gameactivity.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    LayoutParams layout = (LayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams();
    int margin = layout.topMargin;
    Bitmap cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444); 
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(cs);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2,0,margin, null);
```

(I rotate the image because it is in landscape mode even if I take it in portrait mode so I correct that)

The problem is even if dimensions Canvas = dimensions of bitmap,  I don't see the entire image after my code is executed, it is a bit cropped and of course bitmap2 is not where it should be. 
Maybe I should take the dimensions of the screen instead??

Comment: And if I don't resize the originale bitmap2 I have a java outofmemory error

Answer (score 1):

You can use drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint) for drawing bitmaps:

```
Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap2.getWidth(), bitmap2.getHeight());
Rect dst = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, src, dst, null);
```

Also if you rotating your image than width and height will be swapped here:

```
bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap,0,0,width,height,matrix,true);
```

Comment: Interesting answer but even when I do that the main picture (bitmap is cropped) and the entire image does nor fill the whole screen + what is strange is when i print on my logcat the dimensions after and before the rotations, they are the same!